# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'T.ID'

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I have the following class with Firebase functions:

```
class FIRFirestoreService {

private init() {}
static let shared = FIRFirestoreService()

func configure() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
}

private func reference(to collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference) -> CollectionReference {
    return Firestore.firestore().collection(collectionReference.rawValue)
}

func create<T: Encodable>(for encodableObject: T,in collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference) {
    do {
        let json = try encodableObject.toJson(excluding: ["id"])
        reference(to: collectionReference).addDocument(data: json)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func read<T: Decodable>(from collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference, returning objectType: T.Type, completion: @escaping ([T]) -> Void) {
    reference(to: collectionReference).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, _) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
        do {
            var objects = [T]()
            for document in snapshot.documents {
                let object = try document.decode(as: objectType.self)
                objects.append(object)
            }
            completion(objects)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func update<T: Encodable & Identifiable>(for encodableObject: T, in collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference) {
    do {
        let json = try encodableObject.toJson(excluding: ["id"])
        guard let id = encodableObject.id else { throw MyError.encodingError }
        reference(to: collectionReference).document(id).setData(json)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func delete<T: Identifiable>(_ identifiableObject: T, in collectionReference: FIRCollectionReference) {
    do {
        guard let id = identifiableObject.id else { throw MyError.encodingError }
        reference(to: collectionReference).document(id).delete()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

}

Here is my Encodable+Extension file

```
extension Encodable {
func toJson(excluding keys: [String] = [String]()) throws -> [String : Any] {
    let objectData = try JSONEncoder().encode(self)
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: objectData, options: [])
    guard var json = jsonObject as? [String : Any] else { throw MyError.encodingError }

    for key in keys {
        json[key] = nil
    }

    return json
}
```

}

And here is the Snapshot+Extension file

```
extension DocumentSnapshot {
func decode<T: Decodable>(as objectType: T.Type, includingId: Bool = true) throws -> T {
    var documentJson = data()
    if includingId {
        documentJson!["id"] = documentID
    }

    let documentData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: documentJson, options: [])
    let decodedObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(objectType, from: documentData)

    return decodedObject
}
```

}

In two functions (update and delete) the following line:

```
guard let id = encodableObject.id else { throw MyError.encodingError }
```

Gets flagged with the following:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'T.ID'

Why is that and how do I fit it?

Comment: Please show the code where you use it, it looks like conflict of types during generics resolving.

Comment: That's the thing, I haven't been able to use it yet. I'll post all the relevant code below...

Comment: I have edited the initial question with the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, it indicates that the `guard`ed object is non-optional.

Indeed the [Identifiable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable) requires a non-optional `id` property so replace

```
guard let id = identifiableObject.id else { throw MyError.encodingError }
```

with

```
let id = identifiableObject.id
```